# Cannot find parameter field Pm-Command.Name in subreport 12. SAP B1

Tags: crystal-reports, sapb1, crystal-reports-2011

I created report which has sub report in Crystal Reports 2011 in two different databases, I set Link between main report and its subreport, My report works fine in crystal report design but if I import it in SAP B1 9.2 PL10 I get error message while previewing

> Cannot find parameter field Pm-Command.Name in subreport 12.

I tried to do research but there is no answer I got. The parameter which has error is the parameter links subreport and main report.

I tried to change subreport links but error is still same
Below is formula of subreport parameter which causes that error.

```
{Command.Name} = {?Pm-Command.Name}
```

Please anyone can help me to solve this issue

Comment: I have checked the issue but I do know how to solve it.

If Main report has one subreport it works fine in crystal report design and SAP B1, but if I add another subreport (second subreport) it only works fine in crystal report but not in SAP B1 where it displays error message Cannot find parameter field Pm-Command.Name in subreport NameHere

Main report has parameters FromDate and ToDate, Subreports have parameters FromDate, ToDate and Pm-Command.Name.

How can I use more than one subreport in crystal report and SAP B1?